# Using isort to remove imports without making other changes

Tags: python, isort

I have a project that I've recently upgraded to Python 3. Now that I've dropped Python 2 support, I'd now like to remove the `from __future__` imports, and think I might be able to use `isort` ([docs](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/add_or_remove_imports.html))

Say I have a file `myfile.py`:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from foo import bar
import baz
```

I can run the following command,

```
isort --rm __future__ myfile.py
```

and it rewrites my file to

```
import baz
from foo import bar
```

It's removed the `__future__` import as required, but it's also reordered the other imports. This will make it harder to review the patch when there are thousands of files in the project.

Is it possible to run `isort` so that it *only* removes the import, and doesn't make any other changes?

Comment: One possible solution: Run isort normally to sort imports and commit those changes. Then run it again to remove the `__future__` imports. Then commit that. At least this gives the reviewer separate commits to look at.

Comment: Interestingly the documentation says "without having to be concerned with how it was originally formatted" which to me implies that it shouldn't sort existing imports when it removes one. Either this is poorly worded or the feature doesn't work as intended....not sure which.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thanks for the suggestion. As an experiment I tried applying `isort` first, removing the imports in a second commit, then interactively rebasing to remove the initial changes. In my project, there were too many merge conflicts for this to be useful.

Comment: I’m not looking to introduce isort to this project at the moment, so it probably isn’t the best tool to use to remove these imports. I’ll look at using something else, e.g. sed.

Comment: *without having to be concerned with how it was originally formatted* - I understood this to mean that if I used `isort` to remove `os.path`, it would find `import os.path`, `from os import path`, and variations with different whitespace.